# Why matrix never ends loading?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI have these 2 tables:

[image]

In a Matrix (in rows) I drag:
AD group , Dept, Employee

In Values I have: Measure = DISTINCTCOUNT(Table2[Dept])

Why is that it never finishes loading, what is so expensive?

Comment: Make sure that there is a valid relationship between the two tables.  It's quite likely that you've got situation where your distinct count is evaluating on every element of a cross join.   It could be a whole lot of processing depending on the size of the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Short answer : DistinctCount is always expensive.

You need to check your measure and test your report performance.

1. Your First Measure:

   Measure = DISTINCTCOUNT(Table2[Dept])

And DAX Studio Report Performance:

[image: DAX_01]

Report:

[image: Report]

2. Now let's write your measure in another way:

   Measure2 = SUMX(DISTINCT(Table2[Dept]),1)

And DAX Studio Report Performance:

[image: DAX_02]

Report:

[image: Reportttt]

As you can see : 2nd Code is slightly much better even if datasets are small. If data grows, you will better understand difference.

Result:

1. First check your DAX Code:
2. Run performance analyzer and check report performance. I hope It is useful for you!